# Half of tkinter button border white?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For some odd reason my tkinter button's border is half white half black, is this normal/fixable? I want the whole border to be black

```
        btn_Next1 = tk.Button(self, text="Next",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        btn_Next1.configure(font=buttonfont, fg='#ffffff', background='#00497a', highlightbackground='#3E4149', borderwidth=2)
```

[image: Half black half white button]

Comment: Yes, that is what gives it the visual effect of being raised. If it was a solid color it wouldn't look like it was a button.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `relief` property for the button, by default it is `RAISED`. Perhaps you want `FLAT`?

From [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm):

```
relief=
    Border decoration. Usually, the button is SUNKEN when pressed, 
    and RAISED otherwise. Other possible values are GROOVE, RIDGE, 
    and FLAT. Default is RAISED. (relief/Relief)
```

Comment: So raised makes half of the border white and the other half black?

Comment: @ecorp Seems like it. I imagine `SUNKEN` is the same, with the highlights reversed.

Comment: @ecorp Not odd, just 90's era skeumorphism! http://babich.biz/buttons-in-ui-design-the-evolution-of-style-and-best-practices/

Comment: thank you for that link! Tkinter is about as pretty as a Proboscis Monkey but I can throw enough makeup on it to do what I need it to do.